# How to do individual axis labeling with use SciDraw multipanel figures?

Tags: plotting, graphics, packages, scidraw

I am trying to make a 6 panel figure for publication where each X and Y axis has its own label. Here is simplified code and its output:

```
Get["SciDraw`"]
Figure[
 Multipanel[{
   
   (*FIGURES HERE*)
   FigurePanel[{ },{1, 1}];
   
   },
  
  (**)
  Dimensions -> {2, 3},

  (*AXIS STUFF HERE*)
  XPlotRange -> {0, 1},
  YPlotRange -> {0, 1},
  YFrameLabel -> {
    {"y label 1", "y label 2", "y label 3"},
    {"y label 4", "y label 5", "y label 6"}
    },
  XPanelGaps -> 0.5,
  YPanelGaps -> 0.5
  ],
 Background -> White,
 CanvasSize -> {10, 5}
 ]
```

[image: Should have y labels 1 through 6 in order with the letters]

So my question is how do I get different X/Y axes on each panel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ShowFrameLabel -> True`.  You may also want to use `ShowTickLabels -> True`.  The options have the usual variants, i.e. `XShowFrameLabel`, `XXShowFrameLabel`, etc.

---

```
Figure[
 Multipanel[
  {
   FigurePanel[{}, {1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {"foo", "bar"}];

   FigurePanel[{}, {2, 1}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"rabbit", "dog"}, 
    ShowTickLabels -> False (* in this panel we don't want tick labels *)
   ];

   FigurePanel[{}, {1, 2}, 
    FrameLabel -> {"macaw", "jaguar"}, 
    ShowFrameLabel -> False (* in this panel we don't want fame labels *)
   ];

   FigurePanel[{}, {2, 2}, FrameLabel -> {"wombat", "thylacine"}];
   },
  Dimensions -> {2, 2},
  XPanelGaps -> 0.2, YPanelGaps -> 0.2,
  ShowFrameLabel -> True, (* by default we want all frame labels, not just on the edges *)
  ShowTickLabels -> True (* by default we want all tick labels, not just on the edges *)
  ],
 CanvasSize -> {8, 6}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So in the case of a 2x3 panel figure, is the default with Multipanel `XShowFrameLable -> {{False,False,False},{True,True,True}}` and `YShowFrameLable -> {{True,False,False},{True,False,False}}`?

Looking through the user guide documentation, I don't see any mention of that.

Comment: @Eric I don't know the details of how these options are handled.  I never use this syntax that you show.  I either use a global setting in `Multipanel`, where the default is `ShowFrameLabel -> False` and causes the result you showed, or otherwise I put the options within `FigurePanel`s directly.  That way I know what option is associated with what panel, even if I change the panel arrangement.  I never use lists of boolean values directly within `Multipanel`.

Comment: maybe I'm misinterpreting what you're saying, but I saw somewhere in the documentation that figurepanels within multipanels will only use XYoptions specified from multipanel. Is it that they will preferentially apply multipanel options over figurepanel options?

Comment: @Eric I don't know.  I added an example.

Comment: Excuse me!You code cannot be run in 10.3.1?

Comment: @yode I assume you installed and loaded the SciDraw package?