# SciDraw: Nested Multipanels

Tags: scidraw

I would like to construct a nested Multipanel with `SciDraw`. That is, I want the first 5 elements of a 3x2 Multipanel grid to be regular plots, but the last element to be a Multipanel on its own. I hope my goal becomes clear from my attempts so far:

```
Needs["SciDraw`"]
```

**First try: Nesting Multipanels**

```
Figure[
 {Multipanel[
    {
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 1}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 2}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 3}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {2, 1}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {2, 2}];
     FigurePanel[{
       Multipanel[{              
          FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 1}, 
           XShowTickLabels -> True];
          FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 2}];
          },
         Dimensions -> {1, 2},
         XPanelGaps -> .1
         ];
       },
      {2, 3},
      Frame -> False
      ];
     },
    Dimensions -> {2, 3},
    XPanelGaps -> .1,
    YPanelGaps -> .1
    ];
  },
 CanvasSize -> {5, 3.5}
 ]
```

[image]

Problem here: I can't set tick or axes labels on the two plots at position {3,2}. It seems that the `Frame->False` of the outer FigurePanel erases anything outside the frame. Also, the outer frame edges seem thinner in the nested multipanel.

**Second try: Manual stacking of two Multipanels**

```
Figure[
 {Multipanel[
   {
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 1}];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 2}];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 3}];
    },
   Dimensions -> {1, 3},
   XPanelGaps -> .1,
   PanelRegion -> Scaled[{{0, 1}, {0.55, 1}}]
   ];
  Multipanel[{
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 1}];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 2}];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 3}];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 4}];
    },
   Dimensions -> {1, 4},
   XPanelGaps -> {.13, 0.13, 0.07},
   XPanelSizes -> {4/3, 4/3, 1, 0.3},
   PanelRegion -> Scaled[{{0, 1}, {0, 0.45}}]
   ];
  },
 CanvasSize -> {5, 3.5}
 ]
```

[image]

Problem here: The vertical alignment and horizontal size adjustment between the top and the bottom row needs to be done manually and is never precise.

**Question:**

How can I properly define a nested multipanel? That is, how can I combine a mathematically precise alignment of the panels with a full flexibility to use tick and axes labels?

I'm specifically looking for solutions using `SciDraw`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just come across this question when I encountered the same question. After skimming the manual, I think I have found the solution on both your **first** and **second** try. I also used a **third** way to implement this kind of irregular grids(or nested multipanels in your language).

Modification to your **first** try:

Basically, the idea is correct. But to implement it, we need to achieve :
(1) show individual frame label in multipanel (2) suppress the output of *exterior* frame label in FigurePanel where the inset multipanel is at.

The solution to the first issue can be found here [How to do individual axis labeling with use SciDraw multipanel figures?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107620/how-to-do-individual-axis-labeling-with-use-scidraw-multipanel-figures). Basically, we need to add `ShowFrameLabel -> True` in `Multipanel`.

The solution to the second issue can be *found* in the SciDrawGuide.pdf in Page 93. (I am using version 0.0.7, the latest release till now) The option is `Clip->False`. According to the user's guide,  it says

> However, with Clip->False, graphics will be allowed to extend out to the
>   edge of the canvas

Therefore, we can set `Clip->False` to allow the inset multipanel to plot outside the corresponding FigurePanel.

The rest of the adjustments are trivial.

In short, the complete code will look like(I also make the gaps larger in order to fit the frame labels):

```
Figure[{Multipanel[{FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1,
        1}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 2}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 3}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {2, 1}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {2, 2}];
     FigurePanel[{Multipanel[{FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[
             Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 1}, XShowTickLabels -> True, 
           XTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, .5, 5], 
           YTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, .5, 5]];

          FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 2}, 
           XTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, .5, 5], 
           YTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, .5, 5], 
           YShowTickLabels -> True];}, Dimensions -> {1, 2}, 
         XPanelGaps -> .3, ShowFrameLabel -> True];}, {2, 3}, 
      Frame -> False, Clip -> False, PanelLetter -> None];}, 
    Dimensions -> {2, 3}, XPanelGaps -> .2, YPanelGaps -> .1];}, 
 CanvasSize -> {5, 3.5}]
```

[image: Output of *first* method]

Modification to your **second** try is to use two sets of grid(multipanel array) with allowing empty panel. This is already addressed in @Max answer.

The **third** way:

This is mentioned in Sec 10.2 Page 98, where you can use `RegionExtension` and `RegionDisplacement` to manipulate each single panel. In this case, you may create a 2*4 grid and extend the panel at (1,3) to (1,4) while leaving (1,4) empty. To make equal width, `XPanelSizes` should be `{1,1,.5,.5}`.

The code will be like:

```
fig3 = Figure[{Multipanel[{
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 1}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 2}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {1, 3}, 
      RegionExtension -> {.35, 0}, RegionDisplacement -> {.35, 0}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {2, 1}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {2, 2}];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {2, 3}, 
      XTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, .5, 5], 
      YTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, .5, 5], YShowTickLabels -> True];
     FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]]}, {2, 4}, 
      XTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, .5, 5], 
      YTicks -> LinTicks[0, 1, .5, 5], YShowTickLabels -> True];
     }, Dimensions -> {2, 4}, XPanelGaps -> .2, YPanelGaps -> 0.2, 
    XPanelSizes -> {1, 1, .5, .5}, ShowFrameLabel -> True]}, 
  CanvasSize -> {5, 3.5}]
```

[image]

Other adjustments like `PanelLetter` and `FrameTextNudge` can be easily assigned in each `FigurePanel`.

P.S. In the documentation, it is said `Clip` is "under development and subject to change". So IMHO I assume the third way is more preferred by the intention of the author.

Answer (score 1):

@Felix: I use `SciDraw`'s predecessor `LevelScheme`. However, it may be that some of this code is useful.

I'm unhappy with the magic numbers, (`ps`, `pa`), but neverthless offer:

```
Manipulate[
 Figure[{
   SetOptions[SchemeObject, FontFamily -> "Helvetica LT Std", 
    FontSize -> 08],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .97}, "Title", FontSize -> 12, 
    FontWeight -> Bold, Offset -> {0, 0}],
   ScaledLabel[{.5, .945}, "subtitle", FontSize -> 10, 
    Offset -> {0, 0}],
   Multipanel[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
    {2, 4},
    XPlotRanges -> {0, 1},
    YPlotRanges -> {0, 1},
    XFrameLabels -> {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4"},
    BufferB -> 5,
    YFrameLabels -> {"y1", "y2"}, 
    BufferL -> 7,
    XFrameTicks -> {LinTicks[0, 1, 1, 1], LinTicks[0, 1, 1, 1], 
      LinTicks[0, 1, 1, 1], LinTicks[0, 1, 1, 1]},
    YFrameTicks -> {LinTicks[0, 1, 1, 1], LinTicks[0, 1, 1, 1]},
    XGapSizes -> .05, YGapSizes -> .1,
    XPanelSizes -> {1, 1, 1, .25},
    YPanelSizes -> {1, 1},
    First -> "A",
    Order -> Vertical
    ],
   FigurePanel[{1, 1}, ShowPanelLetter -> True],
   FigurePanel[{1, 2}, ShowPanelLetter -> True],
   FigurePanel[{1, 3}, ShowPanelLetter -> True, PanelShift -> {ps, 0},
     PanelAdjustments -> {{pa, 0}, {0, 0}}],
   FigurePanel[{2, 1}, ShowPanelLetter -> True],
   FigurePanel[{2, 2}, ShowPanelLetter -> True],
   FigurePanel[{2, 3}, ShowPanelLetter -> True],
   FigurePanel[{2, 4}, ShowPanelLetter -> True]
   },
  ImageSize -> (1*72) *  {PAGEWIDTH, PAGEWIDTH/Sqrt[2]}
  ],
 {{ps, .2, "Shift"}, 0, .5, .01},
 {{pa, .2, "Adj"}, 0, .5, .01}
 ]
```

The thin right frame in Panel H is a result of moving it too far towards the right.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. Could you post a picture of the output, since it does not run with `SciDraw`? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, now I understand your idea. Definitely +1. But the problem is the manual adjustment of panel E, which I would prefer to automate. Let's see if someone else has another idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have your answer!

You just use two canvas-sized Multipanels with different grids. Empty grid spaces are allowed. In your example, the first five plots would be on a 2x3 grid, and the last two plots would be on a 2x6 grid. Here's my code (with some styling to prevent issues):

```
fooPlot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

DefineStyle["fooStyle", {FigurePanel -> {XPlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
    YPlotRange -> {0, 1}, YTickLabelRange -> {0.2, 1}, 
    FrameLabel -> None}}]

Figure[{
  Multipanel[{

    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[fooPlot];}, {1, 1}, PanelLetter -> "(a)"];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[fooPlot];}, {1, 2}, PanelLetter -> "(b)"];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[fooPlot];}, {1, 3}, PanelLetter -> "(c)"];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[fooPlot];}, {2, 1}, PanelLetter -> "(d)"];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[fooPlot];}, {2, 2}, PanelLetter -> "(e)",
      XTickLabelRange -> {0.2, 1}];

    },
   Dimensions -> {2, 3},
   XPanelGaps -> 0.1,
   YPanelGaps -> 0.1
   ];

  Multipanel[{

    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[fooPlot];}, {2, 5}, PanelLetter -> "(f)"];
    FigurePanel[{FigGraphics[fooPlot];}, {2, 6}, PanelLetter -> "(g)"];

    },
   Dimensions -> {2, 6},
   XPanelGaps -> 0.2, (* this should be n times bigger than XPanelGaps for the first Multipanel, where n is how much smaller the panel sizes are, which is proportional to Dimensions. So here, 6/3=2 times bigger. *)
   YPanelGaps -> 0.1,
   XTicks -> None
   ];

  },
 CanvasSize -> {3, 2}*3,
 Style -> "fooStyle"
 ]
```

[image]

If you want any panels to be different sizes, you can use XPanelSizes->{list of widths}.

Comment: Can you make the combined panels (f)+(g) the exact same size as panel (c)?

Comment: @Felix Ah huh I hadn’t noticed that. It seems XPanelGaps defaults to different values for the two grids. Just set XPanelGaps->0.1 (or your desired value) for both grids and the panel sizes should match up, with all horizontal gaps between panels equal.

Comment: Can you demonstrate what you mean? If I'm not mistaken, your code already includes `XPanelGaps->0.1` for both panels and the graphs do not align.

Comment: @Felix, you're right, I didn't realize XPanelGaps was relative, not absolute. I've fixed it by making the second XPanelGaps->0.2 instead of 0.1. If you decide to play around with XPanelSizes, you may need to adjust XPanelGaps more to make it look good.

Comment: Looks great! Even if it has not all the power of really including a sub-multipanel (like easily changing dimensions and spacing within the sub-panel), I'll accept this as the proper answer.