# BarLegend: FrameLabel ruins alignment of BarLegend

Tags: plotting, legending

Take a simple `ContourPlot` or `DensityPlot` with a corresponding `BarLegend`:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic], After]]
```

[image: Simple density plot.]

Note the **perfect** alignment of the `BarLegend` with the contents of the plot. Now, let's label the axes (which one should always do!):

[image: Simple density plot with axes labels.]

The alignment is now ruined! Further investigation reveals the culprit to be the label on the y-axis. Specifying x-axis labels

```
DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic], After], 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", None, "x", None}]
```

works, whereas

```
DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic], After], 
  FrameLabel -> {None, "y", None, None}]
```

and similar combinations involving a y-axis label don't.

This seems to me to more of a bug than a feature. Is there any way to fix this automatically *without* having to manually control the `BarLegend` size and placement? It seems Mathematica is able to do it but some frame setting is throwing it off.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem when I run your code on my system: V11.3 running on MacOS 10.13.4. Please indicate Mathematica version and OS you are using.

Comment: Mathematica version 12.0.0 and Mac OSX 10.12.6

Comment: What happens if you try this: `DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic,  FrameLabel -> {{"lf", "rt"}, {"btm", "top"}}]`?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this on 12.0 on macOS 10.14 on a Retina MacBook Pro.

Comment: @m_goldberg Same problem.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 12 on Win.10 and cannt reproduce this. It gives me a very nice alignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of the [`DensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot) call is a [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended) object, that basically creates a [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid) object that lines up the graphic and the legend. So, to get the size of the legend and the alignment of the legend to match the graphic, we first need to figure out how to do this when using [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid). Consider the following two graphics objects:

```
g = Graphics[{Circle[{1,1}]}, Frame->True, FrameLabel->{{None, None}, {"x", None}}];
b = Graphics[{Rectangle[{0,-100}, {10,100}]}, ImageSize->{Automatic, 360}];
```

which basically have the same shapes as the density plot and the bar legend. Let's see what happens when we put them side by side using [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid):

```
Grid[{{g, b}}]
```

[image]

Not very good. To get the sizes to match, I will use the syntax: `ImageSize -> Automatic -> size` instead of `ImageSize -> size`:

```
Grid[{{Show[g, ImageSize->Automatic->360], Show[b, ImageSize->Automatic->{Automatic, 360}]}}]
```

[image]

Much better. However, the alignment is not quite correct. The only way I know to align two graphics objects in a [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid) when [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding) is involved, is to use `BaselinePosition->Axis`:

```
Grid[{{
    Show[g, ImageSize->Automatic->360, BaselinePosition->Axis],
    Show[b, ImageSize->Automatic->{Automatic, 360}, BaselinePosition->Axis]
}}]
```

[image]

One final issue is that the [`AxesOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesOrigin) of the two objects are not in the same scaled position. I think the [`BarLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend) always uses a raster with the center at `{0,0}`. So, we need to make sure that the graphic axis is also at the center:

```
Grid[{{
    Show[g, ImageSize->Automatic->360, BaselinePosition->Axis, AxesOrigin->{0, 1}],
    Show[b, ImageSize->Automatic->{Automatic, 360}, BaselinePosition->Axis]
}}]
```

[image]

This is basically the way to size and align two graphics objects in a [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid).

Now, unfortunately, [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended) does two things that ruin the above alignment procedure:

```
TracePrint[
    ToBoxes @ DensityPlot[
        Sin[2 x y],
        {x,-2,2},
        {y,-2,2},
        PlotLegends->Placed[BarLegend[Automatic],After],
        FrameLabel->{{None,None},{"x",None}}
    ],
    ToBoxes[_Grid,_] | Pane[_Graphics, __Rule],
    TraceInternal->True,
    TraceAction->Print@*OutputForm@*ReplaceAll[Grid->Inactive[Grid]]
];
```

> ```
> Pane[-Graphics-, Alignment -> Left, AppearanceElements -> None, ImageMargins -> {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}, ImageSizeAction -> ResizeToFit]
>
> Pane[-Graphics-, Alignment -> Left, AppearanceElements -> None, ImageMargins -> {{5, 5}, {5, 5}}, ImageSizeAction -> ResizeToFit]
>
> ToBoxes[Inactive[Grid][Map[RawBoxes, BoxForm`grid$716644, {2}], Alignment -> {Center, Center}, WrappersDump`removeIfDefault[BaselinePosition -> WrappersDump`baselineposition$716644, Automatic], WrappersDump`removeIfDefault[Spacings -> OptionValue[Labeled, {}, Spacings], Automatic], StripOnInput -> True], StandardForm]
>
> ToBoxes[Inactive[Grid][{{RawBoxes[TagBox[ItemBox[PaneBox[TagBox[#1, SkipImageSizeLevel], Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}, BaselinePosition -> Baseline], DefaultBaseStyle -> Labeled], SkipImageSizeLevel]], RawBoxes[ItemBox[#2, DefaultBaseStyle -> LabeledLabel]]}}, Alignment -> {Center, Center}, BaselinePosition -> {1, 1}, StripOnInput -> True], StandardForm]
> ```

Both this [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane) wrapper and the `Alignment -> {Center, Center}` option in the [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid) prevent the above alignment procedure from working. For example, using `Alignment -> {Center, Center}`:

```
Grid[
    {{
        Show[g, ImageSize->Automatic->360, BaselinePosition->Axis, AxesOrigin->{0, 1}],
        Show[b, ImageSize->Automatic->{Automatic, 360}, BaselinePosition->Axis]
    }},
    Alignment->{Center, Center}
]
```

[image]

and similarly for the [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane) option.

So, to fix your issue, we need to do the following:

1. Use the `ImageSize -> Automatic -> size` option setting.
2. Use `BaselinePosition -> Axis`.
3. Avoid using `Alignment ->  {Center, Center}` when constructing the [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid).
4. Avoid wrapping the graphic in [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane).
5. Make sure that the [`AxesOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesOrigin) of the graphic is in the center of the graphic.

Here is one approach that does this. First define a [`LegendFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendFunction) that fixes the [`BarLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend) [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) options and removes the [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane) wrapper:

```
fixLegend[size_][legend_] := ReplaceAll[
    legend,
    {
        g_Graphics :> Show[g, ImageSize->Automatic->{Automatic, size}, BaselinePosition->Axis],
        Pane -> Function@#
    }
]
```

Then, define a wrapper function that removes the unwanted [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid) alignment during box generation:

```
MakeBoxes[stripGridAlignemnt[expr_], form_] ^:= ReplaceAll[
    MakeBoxes[expr, form],
    Rule[GridBoxAlignment, _] -> Sequence[]
]
```

Now, we are ready to create the desired output:

```
stripGridAlignemnt @ DensityPlot[
    Sin[2 x y],
    {x,-2,2},
    {y, 0, 4},
    BaselinePosition->Axis,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 2},
    ImageSize->Automatic->360,
    PlotLegends->Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendFunction -> fixLegend[360]], After],
    FrameLabel->{{None,None},{"x",None}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great detailed answer!

Comment: What does `a` mean in `ImageSize -> a -> b` when `a` is not `Automatic`?

Comment: It would be really useful to be able to align the baseline on the frame (not axis) ... Luckily, in this case I had frames, not axes (and when I also have axes, they don't have ticks, so it's easy to replace them with plain lines).

Comment: @Szabolcs `ImageSize -> a -> b` when `a` is a number means that `a` in plot coordinates has size `b`. When `a` is `Automatic` it means the base plot range (before plot range padding) has size `b`. Was there a question in your second comment?

Comment: @Szabolcs I understand your comment now. If you actually displayed axes in the plot, then using `AxesOrigin` to align the graphic would be a problem, because it would also change the position of the axes. I think I have an idea of how to handle this situation using `Inset` to create a graphic where the inset graphic has the correct `AxesOrigin`, while the enclosing graphic has a different `AxesOrigin`.

Comment: @CarlWoll I usually try to align figures (not in the context of legends, just in general) by matching the ImagePadding. [You have a nice tool to get the automatic ImagePadding](https://github.com/carlwoll/GraphicsInformation). I guess a good way would be to use this to find the graphics with the largest padding in the direction of interest (vertical of lining them up horizontally) then set the same padding on all the other graphics.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version (* Wolfram Cloud FrontEnd *)
```

> 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)

We can add the frame labels using [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) instead of using `FrameLabel`

```
ClearAll[addLabels]
addLabels[plot_, labels_, pos_, legpos_ : Right]:= Labeled[First @ plot, 
 Append[labels, plot[[2, 1]]], Append[pos, legpos]]
```

***Examples:***

```
dp1 = DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ImageSize -> 320,  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic], After]];

Row[{dp1, addLabels[dp1, {"x", "y"}, {Bottom , Left}]},  Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{dp1, addLabels[dp1, Style[#, 32] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}, {Bottom , Left, Top}]}, 
 Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

```
cp = ContourPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImageSize -> 320,  
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLayout -> "Row"], Top]];

Row[{cp, addLabels[cp, Style[#, 32] & /@ {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 {Bottom , Left, Right}, Top]}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I do note that the labels are now not centred around the plot but around the plot + legend. Anyhow, I have good reason to believe this issue is a bug as several users cannot replicate it.

Comment: @OldTomMorris, the labels are centered around the plot (not around the plot + legend.)

Comment: Perhaps @OldTomMorris meant to say that the label is centered around the plot *including* ImagePadding, and not just around the plot range. As you can see, the `x` label is located to the left of 0.

Comment: @CarlWoll, oh, he meant plot+labels. Great point; thank you. I don't see an easy and clean fix for that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that I am the few people who can reproduce this "bug". (MMA 12.0 on Windows 10)

I suggest you manually control the height of the image and the size of barlegend. Here is what I used:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 270], After], 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", None, "x", None}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]
```

Output:[image]

Adding y axis label:

```
DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 270], After], 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y", "x", None}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}]
```

[image]

It is not perfect in alignment, but at least, it will not shift uncontrollably, so that you can manually adjust the alignment.

Again, for publication-quality production of figures,  I suggest trying SciDraw. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152074/scidraw-nested-multipanels/200433#200433) might be helpful to your question, as you can treat the bar legend as a side by side nested frame.

Comment: The size of the main image cannot be changed. It is constrained by the physical medium in which it will be printed. I cannot use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica is bad at alignment. However, the job can be done in different ways:

```
f = DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 17, Black, Bold, 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> {"X", "y", "Z", None}]  
Legended[f, 
 Placed[BarLegend[{ColorData[{"BlueGreenYellow", {-1, 1}}], {-1, 1}}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, Blue, Bold}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 250.], {1, .51}]]
```

[image]

You can also use `Grid` when you have more figures as follows:

```
f = DensityPlot[Sin[2 x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 17, Black, Bold, 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> None, FrameLabel -> {"X", "y", "Z", None}, 
  ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> 300]
Legended[Grid[{{f, f}, {f, f}}, Spacings -> {-12, -12}], 
 Placed[BarLegend[{ColorData[{"BlueGreenYellow", {-1, 1}}], {-1, 1}}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 13, Blue, Bold}, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 313.], {0.94, .45}]]
```

[image]