# How to control the padding below a BarLegend?

Tags: legending

[`BarLegend`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) has an annoyingly large space at the bottom. I can see that this was added to make it line up with the frame of the plot when there is a bottom frame label (see e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204519/12)), but this does not work out well for all plot sizes, and it causes problems in specific situations.

How can I control this space?

Select the legend to see the spacing better:

[image]

This space is also much too large for a legend label placed below the legend.

```
Row[
 {Framed@BarLegend["Rainbow", 
    Method -> {ImagePadding -> None, ImageMargins -> None, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None}, LegendMargins -> 0, 
    LegendLabel -> "foo"],
  Framed@BarLegend["Rainbow", 
    Method -> {ImagePadding -> None, ImageMargins -> None, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None}, LegendMargins -> 0, 
    LegendLabel -> Placed["foo", Below]]}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Disgustingly, you can pass negative values to `LegendMargins`: `BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-10, 0}}]`

Comment: @CarlLange Excellent! Post answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass negative values to `LegendMargins` like so:

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-15, 0}}]
```

[image]

Happily, this appears to work quite stably, even though it feels wrong:

```
Row[{Framed@
   BarLegend["Rainbow", 
    Method -> {ImagePadding -> None, ImageMargins -> None, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None}, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-15, 0}}, 
    LegendLabel -> "foo"], 
  Framed@BarLegend["Rainbow", 
    Method -> {ImagePadding -> None, ImageMargins -> None, 
      PlotRangePadding -> None}, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-15, 0}}, 
    LegendLabel -> Placed["foo", Below]]}]
```

[image]

I am a little disappointed that the "zero-point" still has such a large margin on it - having to pass negative values feels like a hack. I almost wish it didn't work so the margin could be called a bug...

Comment: It's really ugly, but I was not able to find any other solution, and I'm happy that it moves things forward.

Comment: (+1) If we replace `LegendLabel -> "foo"` with `LegendLabel["foo", Above]`, then we can use slightly simpler form `Row[Framed@
   BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-15, 0}},  LegendLabel -> Placed["foo",#]]&/@{Above, Below}]` without the need for `Method` suboptions.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a custom `LegendFunction` (to inject the option `ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}` to the graphics object produced by `BarLegend`)

```
ClearAll[lgF]
lgF = Show[Cases[#, _Graphics, All],
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}]&;

Row[Framed @ BarLegend["Rainbow", 
   LegendLabel -> Placed["foo", #], 
   LegendFunction -> lgF] & /@ {Above, Below}]
```

[image]

Somehow, using the same option as a `Method` sub-option does not work. (Apparently, it is overridden during processing.)